# Table format when export to excel PHP

Tags: php, html, excel, export, html-table

I'm having issues exporting to Excel a table from PHP.

Headers somehow are larger than other cells.

[image]

Colored cells look bigger than data cells, here`s the table export html:

```
$table = "<table border='1' cellspacing='12' cellpadding='12' class='table table-bordered table-responsive statistics'>";
$currentDay = "";
$currentDate = "";
if(isset($allStatistics[0][24]) && isset($allStatistics[0][10])){
    $currentDay = $allStatistics[0][24];
    $currentDate = $allStatistics[0][10];
}
foreach ($allStatistics as $index => $statistic) {
    $debt = $debt + $statistic[7];
    $payed = $payed + $statistic[8];

    //print_r($statistic);
    if($index == 0){
        $table .= "<tr><th style='font-size: 22px;background-color: #".random_color()."' colspan='9'>".$currentDay." - ".$statistic[10]."</th></tr>";
        $table .= "<tr><th colspan='6'></th></tr>";
    }
    else if($statistic[10] != $currentDate){
        $currentDay = $statistic[24];
        $currentDate = $statistic[10];
        $table .= "<tr><th colspan='6'></th></tr>";
        $table .= "<tr><th style='font-size: 22px;background-color: #".random_color()."' colspan='9'>".$statistic[24]." - ".$statistic[10]."</th></tr>";
        $table .= "<tr><th colspan='6'></th></tr>";
    }
    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<th style='font-size: 17px;'>".$statistic[17]." ".$statistic[18]." (dni: ".$statistic[20]." ) </th>";
    $table .= "<th style='font-size: 17px;'>de <strong>".$statistic[13]."</strong> a <strong>".$statistic[15]."</strong></th>";
    $table .= "<th style='font-size: 17px;'>".($statistic[4] == 0 ? "fijo: <strong>no</strong>" : "fijo: <strong>si</strong>")."</th>";
    $table .= "<th style='font-size: 17px;'> <strong>".$statistic[24]."</strong> a las ".$statistic[26]."</th>";
    $table .= "<th style='font-size: 17px;'> reservado: ".$statistic[11]."</th>";
    $table .= "<th style='font-size: 17px;'> debe: <strong>$".$statistic[7]."</strong>, pago: <strong>$".$statistic[8]."</strong></th>";
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "<tr><th colspan='6'></th></tr>";
$table .= "<tr><th colspan='6' style='font-size: 20px;background-color: #000;color:#FFF;'><span style='color: #BBB;'>se debe en total:</span> <strong>$".$debt."</strong><span style='color: #BBB;'> y se cobro en total:</span> <strong>$".$payed."</strong></th></tr>";
$table .= "</table>";
```

I tried colspan and whatever should work for tables normally, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Most of your colspans are 6 (A-F in Excel column names), your first colspan is 9 (A-I), so the colspan 9 will be longer

Comment: omg, i never saw that colspan='9' thanks man.